# Convert list to string

Tags: python, list, formatting, indexing, tuples

I have this list:

```
scores = [
    ('WillyCaballero', '2'),
    ('Angeleri', '2'),
    ('Antunes', '2'),
    ('FlavioFerreira', '2'),
    ('Camacho', '2'),
    ('SamuGarc\xc3\xada', '2'),
    ('I\xc3\xb1igoMart\xc3\xadnez', '2'),
    ('Jos\xc3\xa9\xc3\x81ngel', '6')
    ...
]
```

How to store in one str variable and output like this format?:

```
Willy Caballero 2   
Angeleri 2  
Antunes 2  
...
```

Comment: Do you just want to print or do you want to store as well?

Comment: ok check my answer and you'll get an array of the scores in a string

Comment: do you want one string with all of the scores in, or do you want to keep a list of seperate scores in string form? like this; ['Willy Caballero 2', 'Angeleri 2', 'Antunes 2'...]

Comment: I want one string with all of the scores in.

Comment: @pythonian29033 the OP *does* need `\n` then.

Answer (score 6):

Using [`str.join`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join), join elements with `whitespace` first and then with `'\n'`

```
In [25]: print '\n'.join(' '.join(s) for s in scores)
Willy Caballero 2
Angeleri 2
Antunes 2
Flavio Ferreira 2
...
```

Comment: @pythonian29033 why not ;P

Answer (score 0):

```
str = '\n'.join(' '.join(s) for s in scores)
print(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in scores:
    print i[0],i[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edited**

```
>>> out = map(' '.join, p)
>>> for i in out:
...     print i
... 
WillyCaballero 2
Angeleri 2
Antunes 2
>>>
```

Comment: This only concatenates the tuples inside that list in another list of strings. It does not generate one very long string.

Comment: `out` is still a list.

Comment: he wants to store output somewhere so i am doing this

Comment: OP wants to "store in one str variable".

Answer (score 0):

I would do this;

```
scoresList = ''
for score in scores:
   scoresList += ' '.join(score) + '\n'
#end loop
```

Comment: This does not fix your problem as it merely *prints* but does not *create a string*.

Comment: this creates a *list*, not a *string*.